# Opening workbooks via hyperlink and then using Hyperlink name as workbook reference

Tags: vba, excel, reference, hyperlink

I'm trying to take the hyperlink workbook name and put it into my code.

```
Sub Workbook()

    Dim vbaname as string
    Dim WBMaster As Workbook, WBSource As Workbook
    Dim WSMaster As Worksheet, WSSource As Worksheet

    Range("b7").Hyperlinks(1).Follow

    'returns the hyperlink text "Vba Source test"
    VbaName = """" & Range("B7").Text & """"

    Set WBSource = Workbooks(VbaName)
```

I get a subscript out of range bug. Is there another way to do this. I just want to be able to put the hyperlink text into that bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `Debug.Print` your `VbaName` it actually holds the value of `B7` but the active window ( the followed one from hyperlink ). If you want to get the name of the workbook from the hyperlink, youre working in, then use this code

```
Sub GetWorkbookName()
    MsgBox "the name of the workbook in the hyperlink is: " & vbCrLf & _
            getWorkbookName(Range("B7").Text)
End Sub

Private Function getWorkbookName(hyperLink As String) As String
    Dim i&
    For i = 1 To Len(hyperLink)
        If StrComp(Left(Right(hyperLink, i), 1), "\", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            getWorkbookName = Right(hyperLink, i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

---

On the other hand, I think you are trying to open the workbook from the hyperlink and assign a reference to it. The way you go about it it's not the right approach. I think you may want to consider doing it this way:

```
Sub Workbook()

    Dim wbFromHyperLink As String
    Dim WBSource As Workbook

    MsgBox "the name of the workbook in the hyperlink is: " & vbCrLf & _
            getWorkbookName(Range("B7").Text)

    wbFromHyperLink = getWorkbookName(Range("B7").Text)

    'Range("b7").Hyperlinks(1).Follow

    Set WBSource = Workbooks.Open(Range("B7").Text)

    ' do not forget to close and free the object
    ' WBSource.Saved = True
    ' WBSource.Close
    ' Set WBSource = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function getWorkbookName(hyperLink As String) As String
    Dim i&
    For i = 1 To Len(hyperLink)
        If StrComp(Left(Right(hyperLink, i), 1), "\", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            getWorkbookName = Right(hyperLink, i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  

My macro is going to extract data from the hyperlink workbooks. It going to open 4 workbooks and then execute the code which needs the workbook names as reference for the syntax.